# Compiling the MongoDB c++ driver without _UNICODE

Tags: c++, mongodb, compiler-errors, driver

I'm trying to compile the MongoDB c++ driver into my project and I've run across an interesting error.

in util/text.h, you can find this code:

```
/* like toWideString but UNICODE macro sensitive */
# if !defined(_UNICODE)
#error temp error 
    inline std::string toNativeString(const char *s) { return s; }
# else
    inline std::wstring toNativeString(const char *s) { return toWideString(s); }
# endif
```

It looks like you should be able to compile it without the _UNICODE define, yet there is this seemingly arbitrary line #error temp error which causes the failure. On Github, this seems to have been the case for the lifetime of the file. Does anyone know if it's safe to remove it?

Unfortunately I can't just compile this project in unicode because there are a number of unicode incompatible sources in the project as well.

Cheers

Kyle

Comment: This question was answered [on the mongodb-user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/0n3dosIy9XY): "It looks like leftover stuff that should be cleaned up. We always build with _UNICODE defined, so we never hit this #error. The main (only?) thing that _UNICODE does is select the W form of Windows APIs that have both A (ANSI) and W (wide) forms when you leave out the suffix." ... "I don't know if it has even been possible to build a "non-Unicode" version of MongoDB but it certainly isn't possible now."